# Finding Windows API Vulnerabilities

Tags: windows, api, privilege-escalation

Currently I'm reading about the Windows API's like CreateProcess and others.

Also I took a look into the Source of the Powershell Script which used the [MS16-032](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2016/ms16-032) vulnerability.

My Question is: Which ways can you take to find such vulnerabilities in the API's or general to find things like this?

I watched Videos about Windows Kernel vulnerabilities, but can't find any good Documentation where this is described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Userland:**

understand how the Windows native API works, e.g. something like (and probably not accurate): ZwCreateProcess -> NTCreateProcess -> CreateProcess 
https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/
https://www.google.com/shopping/product/10794697035904501181?q=native+api+book&biw=1486&bih=811&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFzNPlkLLWAhVkJcAKHdwGDRYQ8wIIgwMwAA

Windows Internals:
[https://www.amazon.com/Windows-2000-Native-API-Reference/dp/1578701996](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1578701996)

You'll also want to know x86/x64 calling conventions (STDcall), e.g. how arguments are passed and return values.

Last, what the OS expects and how the return values are used.

**Ring0**:

Uninformed.org has a good writeup:
http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=10&a=2